# Fido2 on Lollipop

Tags: android, android-security, webauthn, fido

I want to implement Fido2 in my application. I found webauthn implementation here https://github.com/duo-labs/android-webauthn-authenticator and it is using BiometricPrompt. How should it work on older devices which don't have fingerprint functionality? I know that there is compat BiometricPrompt which should work below Android 9, but what about Android 5?

Answer (score 0):

The library you linked to probably uses Android's [`BiometricPrompt#authenticate(CryptoObject)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricPrompt#authenticate(android.hardware.biometrics.BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject,%20android.os.CancellationSignal,%20java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20android.hardware.biometrics.BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback)) and/or [`FingerprintManager#authenticate(CryptoObject)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager#authenticate(android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager.CryptoObject,%20android.os.CancellationSignal,%20int,%20android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback,%20android.os.Handler)).

The compat library that you're talking about is probably [`androidx.biometric`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/biometric), which internally invokes BiometricPrompt or FingerprintManager depending on the API level.

Since the FingerprintManager API was introduced in API23 (Android 6), there's no way to use biometric authentication on older API levels. Even if there was, there is no API to integrate biometric sensors with KeyStore operations, as [`setUserAuthenticationRequired(boolean)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder.html#setUserAuthenticationRequired(boolean)), etc were introduced in API23 as well.